# Why Apache 2.4.41 installed on my system

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, apache-httpd, docker

Three days ago I noticed that my localhost on port 80 was occupied by an Apache server. I uninstalled it and started to find out if it was a sign of some kind of malware.

I found out from the logs:

1. I definitely didn't install it myself, because there was no apt-get install apache2 command or anything similar in bash
2. As I found out from the system logs, this server was installed along with the packages that are included in the git dependencies. That said, git was already previously installed on the system. That said, apache2 (I checked via `apt-cache rdepends`) was not a dependency of any other package.
3. In the interval that apache2 with dependencies was installed, I was installing docker using the tutorial from the official site. After installing apache2 directly, I started the docker installation.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
   sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:20.10.9~3-0~ubuntu-focal docker-ce-cli=5:20.10.9~3-0~ubuntu-focal containerd.io
   ```

apache2 dependencies in "secret" installing

[image: apache2 dependencies in "secret" installing]

end of "secret" installation and beginning of docker installing

[image: end of "secret" installation and beginning of docker installing]

[logs from the day Apache2 was installed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y_pnwy6G9OWER-k8vJX71z7-Uv1fhJ1Z/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

With default `apt` settings, installing `git-all` causes `apache2` to be installed because [`git-all`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/git-all) depends on [`gitweb`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/gitweb) which recommends [`apache2`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/apache2) (or `lynx` or a package providing `httpd`).

Removing `git-all` wouldn’t automatically remove `apache2`; you’d have to run `apt autoremove` (and if any other installed package even suggests `apache2`, it wouldn’t be removed anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the constructive answer! Bottom line: is Apache2 needed for gitweb to work properly or can it be removed from the system without any consequences?

Comment: `gitweb` provides a web interface to git repositories, and relies on a web server. It can work with servers other than `apache2`, so you can remove `apache2`; but if you don’t want any web server, you might as well remove `gitweb` as well.